# Gzip and Encode file in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, gzip

```
with gzip.open(sys.argv[5] + ".json.gz", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
```

It throws:

> TypeError: open() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

But the docs says it exists 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html

**Update**

**How can i encode and zip the file in Python 2.7?**

I tried now this:
(but it don't work)

```
with gzip.open(sys.argv[5] + ".json.gz", mode="w") as outfile:
    outfile = io.TextIOWrapper(outfile, encoding="utf-8")
    json.dump(fdata, outfile, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

> TypeError: must be unicode, not str

What can i do?

Comment: The doc is for Python 3, you tagged the question with Python2.x

Answer (score 2):

Those are the Python 3 docs. The [Python 2 version of `gzip`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/gzip.html) does not allow `encoding=` as a keyword argument to `gzip.open()`.

Comment: and what can i do if i want the file to be zipped and encoded?

Comment: @user4517908 Well, I don't really understand what you're trying to do, honestly. That call wouldn't work in Python 3 either, since `'w'` is a binary mode, and you can't set the encoding when you're writing in a binary mode. I guess you should probably encode the JSON using something like `io.TextIOWrapper` and then gzip it?

Comment: I thought "w" is for writing? But if i zip it in memory i am wasting memory. I want to zip it while writing to the file!

Comment: with codecs.open(sys.argv[5] + ".json", "w", encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
        with gzip.open(outfile, mode = "w") as outfile2:
            json.dump(fdata, outfile2, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False) is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Seems the question has been answered sufficiently, but for your peace of mind: Alternatively to ensure that Python2 uses utf-8 as standard perhaps try the following, as it then becomes unnecessary to specify an encoding:

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```